# clCreateImage2D - Load RGB image

Tags: c, opencv, opencl

I'm trying to load an OpenCV image (`IplImage`) into GPU with `clCreateImage2D`.

Reason of using `IplImage` is, i want to load any kind of image.(jpg, bmp, png).

I can load image using `clCreateImage2D` with `CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR` mem_flags, and `CL_RGB` and `CL_UNORM_SHORT_565` type. But in kernel function `read_imagef` function is not accept `CL_UNORM_SHORT_565` type.

So, how can i send RGB image to OpenCL kernel function?

**Edit:** I converted the input image to 32bit. Bu tnow what would be the `image_channel_order` and `image_channel_data_type`? Order can't be RGBA because it has no alpha channel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

24 bit RGB is not supported by OpenCL. So you have to first convert it to 32 bit RGB and then pass it to the OpenCL kernel

Comment: I converted the input image to 32bit. Bu tnow what would be the `image_channel_order` and `image_channel_data_type`?

Comment: If you converted it to 32 bit you must have set the forth byte to a value that in turn get's interpreted as the alpha channel. Moreover, _you_ chose the order.

Comment: @matthias ok then what will be the data_type? I tried CL_SIGNED_INT32 and CL_UNSIGNED_INT32 and i get invalid image size error from clCreateImage2D.

Comment: `CL_RGBA` and `CL_UNSIGNED_INT8`. If a single pixel is 32 bits, then each component is 8bits, hence `CL_UNSIGNED_INT8`