# Incompatibility of CL_UNSIGNED_INT8 and CL_RGB

Tags: c++, c, image-processing, opencl, gpgpu

Do you know why it is not allowed to create an Image2D - I am using C++ API - instance, which is set to having image format (ImageFormat class) of

- CL_RGB (cl_channel_order)
- CL_UNSIGNED_INT8 (cl_channel_type)?

I looks that now, if I have an image with RGB layout, in which every value (R, G and B) is a eight bit number, I have to either

- manually add alpha values (CL_UNSIGNED_INT8 and CL_RGBA is allowed)
- write a kernel, which accept image as "unsigned char*" and not use Image2D class at all

Here is the table of compatibility: [khronos page](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/cl_image_format.html).

To summarize:

1. Why I am not being able to create CL_UNSIGNED_INT8 and CL_RGB Image2D object?
2. Is there a way to workaround this?
3. Should I even workarounding this? Or should I just use one of mine ways ("CL_UNSIGNED_INT8 and CL_RGBA" or "unsigned char*") to process the image?

PS: I saw e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14362876/clcreateimage2d-load-rgb-image), but it does not explain why the incompatibility occurs.

Comment: The table you linked shows that the format `CL_RGB` can only be used with 16-bit channel data types that pack the RGB data into 5- or 6-bit fields. So the channel data type cannot be `CL_UNSIGNED_INT8`.

Comment: @WeatherVane Indeed. And do you know why it is happen to be like that?  This is the question. "Why the incompatibility occurs?" (the first on the three-questions-list).

Comment: 1) That is how 16-bit colour works - it is like that by definition. 2) You can't contain three 8-bit fields in a 16-bit field. 3) I suspect you want to use 24-bit colour, so find an example, or experiment, but the accepted answer in your SO link explains *"24 bit RGB is not supported by OpenCL."*

Comment: @WeatherVane So if there is no workaround, do you know why 24 bit RGB is not supported by OpenCL? Technical issues or something else?

Comment: I can only guess it's because the standard is aimed at parallel computing and a 24-bit data structure does not fit well with power-of-2 data and address bus sizes.

Comment: You can try if CL_RGx can understand the "x"(discarded) bits as the blue channel. Since it looks like CL_RGx is supported.... But it is still weird why it is not supported, since 24bits is not a strange size for a struct.

Answer (score 0):

See table "Table 5.7 Min. list of supported image formats" in the OpenCL 1.1 specification. An implementation is not required to support any of the CL_RGB image types. You can query your device using `clGetSupportedImageFormats` to see which formats it supports, but it appears that CL_RGB is not one of them. Use CL_RGBA; it is required for most pixel depths.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I saw the similar table in 1.2 specification and the conclusion is similar: the vendor don't have to support CL_RGB and CL_UNSIGNED_INT8 combination. But my question is: do you know why they did not force the companies - which implement OpenCL for their devices - to also implement 24 bit RGB support? Is it not popular enough for being consider as the "must have" implementation? Sorry for my stubbornness, but it would be nice to know, why this decision was made (in my case it means adding the alpha channel to each image, which I am processing).

Comment: I don't know why they didn't "force" 24-bit support but I suspect that not all hardware at the time (and apparently not all now) could easily do it. For one, it doesn't align well with power-of-two bit widths.